# New MAC-address, now I have no network-access

Tags: networking, server, configuration

I run Ubuntu Server 10.10 in VirtualBox with Windows as host. Accidently I choosed to generate a new random MAC-address for my Ubuntu machine in VirtualBox. And now when I have booted my Ubuntu with the new MAC-address, I don't get an external IP-address. I'm using DHCP to get IP-addresses.

I guess I have to run a command and inform my Ubuntu system that the MAC-address has changed to get an external IP-address.

If I execute `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` I get this message:

```
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
Bind socket to interface: No such device
Failed to bring up eth0
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your mac address have changed you no longer have an interface called eth0, this name is reserved for an interface with the "old" mac-address. The "new" interface should have the next free name (eg. ethN).

To see all the interfaces on the machine you can use this command: `ifconfig -a`

If you want to reset the name reservations for network interfaces you can remove the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and restart the machine (or remove/insert the device, though this is not possible in this case).

Alternatively you can change the interface-name that you have configured to what ever the new one is called by changing all occurences of the old name with the new one in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Just used this to move a full **12.04 LTS Server** install onto new server hardware. *After I swapped all drives across, I no longer has any network (on the new hardware).* I actually edited **`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`**, to rename NEW interface as 'eth0'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using static IP on your ubuntu host.

Since you have changed the MAC address, the ubuntu will create a new "eth" for you instead of using the old one.

Modify the file /etc/sysconfig/networks/ifcfg-eth0 to ifcfg-eth1 or setup a static configuration using network manager.

Comment: I am actually using DHCP.

Comment: I don't have a directory `/etc/sysconfig/`

Comment: @Jonas check /etc/network/interfaces maybe

Comment: You probably should edit /etc/network/interfaces and add a line like: auto eth1. Please try to give info about the Ubuntu version that you are using in the question as details like paths can change between versions.

Comment: @Javier: Ok, I have updated my question now.

Comment: @jschoen: Thanks, that worked better. However, now I don't know if you should post your own answer or if the path in this should be edited.

Comment: This reply refers to Red Hat Linux rather than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First in VM Guest create a file named **newfile**:
**sudo nano /etc/init.d/newfile** with two lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ifup eth0
```

next, from console:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/newfile
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/newfile 
sudo update-rc.d newfile defaults
```

I used this solution because eth0 is down after reboot with static IP (with DHCP work fine).

my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
    # The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

(sorry for my english)